# Can I plot a bar plot where the color of each bar depended on whether the value was greater than or less than the prior value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a bar plot where the color of each bar depended on whether the value was greater than or less than the prior value. Can I do this with a list comprehension? My guess was it would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DateRange = pd.date_range('1/31/2019', '6/30/2019', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values':[1,3,2,4,3,5]}, index=DateRange)

clrs = ['green' if row > row.shift(1) else 'red' for row in df['Values']]
plt.bar(df.index, df['Values'], width=5, color=clrs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need only to pass the correct colors:

```
DateRange = pd.date_range('1/31/2019', '6/30/2019', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values':[1,3,2,4,3,5]}, index=DateRange)

# notice the difference with your code
clrs = np.where(df['Values'].diff().gt(0), 'g', 'r')

plt.bar(df.index, df['Values'], width=5, color=clrs)
```

Output:

[image]